# Why does Python throw an error when a substring is not found?

Tags: python, string

What's the design thinking behind this?

To me it's easier to do something like

```
if string.index(substring) > -1:
    # do stuff
```

than trying to catch an exception. If the `substring` is not found, at least your program doesn't break.

Someone told me 'returning -1 is a bad pattern'. Why is that?

What is the Pythonic way for checking substring?

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name. You can't use `str` type/function if you use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: One can argue that a function should expect reasonable input, and raise an exception when this is violated. Unless you know to check for -1, you could accidentally use the return value incorrectly.

Comment: Because [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) says so. Of course, you could use `find`, if you'd like

Comment: Because -1 is a bad sentinel value for "not found"; negative indexing is allowed!  (`find` gets away with it, I guess, because you still have `index` when you need the "strict" - aka "correct" - behavior)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`str.index()` throws an exception; you were perhaps thinking of the [`str.find()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) instead:

```
if string.find(substring) > -1:
```

The [`str.index()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) explicitly states this:

> Like `find()`, but raise `ValueError` when the substring is not found.

However, the *correct* way to test for substring membership is to use `in`:

```
if substring in string:
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this way at least the return type of the function is fixed. Also your example is not pythonic, it should read:

```
if str in string:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Python operates under the principle of "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (EAFP), as explained in [an answer by Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880/2738262). It allows the code for the common path to be kept together, making the logic easier to understand without inline error handling cluttering the flow. And in a program that uses `import threading` for non-blocking I/O, reading the variable only once makes [time-of-check-to-time-of-use (TOCTTOU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) bugs less likely than in look-before-you-leap style that some other languages encourage.

The major drawback of EAFP is that Python's syntax for exception handling doesn't mesh well with functional programming style. You can't catch exceptions for individual elements in the iterable input to a generator expression without defining and naming a function.